# Kotlin classes not available on variant.javaCompiler.doLast

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

I'm trying to weave Java and Kotlin class files with AspectJ the following way:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

    JavaCompile javaCompile = variant.javaCompiler
    javaCompile.doLast {
        String[] args = ["-showWeaveInfo",
                         "-1.8",
                         "-inpath", javaCompile.destinationDir.toString(),
                         "-aspectpath", javaCompile.classpath.asPath,
                         "-d", javaCompile.destinationDir.toString(),
                         "-classpath", javaCompile.classpath.asPath,
                         "-bootclasspath", project.android.bootClasspath.join(
                File.pathSeparator)]
```

I've made sure that the Kotlin paths are included in the appropriate paths, but no Kotlin classes are processed.

How do you make sure that Kotlin class files get processed this way?

Answer (score 1):

the task is called `KotlinCompile`, because the [Gradle Kotlin DSL](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl) differs (here's the [examples](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/tree/master/samples#readme)).

not certain if your script could be directly migrated, but it might be `variant.kotlinCompiler`.

alternatively, it is possible to hook into those tasks alike:

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    doLast {

    }
}
```

that `.kt` is not being processed is because a Java compiler does not recognize them. would assume, that you might require [KAPT](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html), in order to have those AspectJ annotations processed.